# How can you verify immediately that a message was acknowledged when integration testing using Embedded Kafka in Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: apache-kafka, integration-testing, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

We use Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder (with Project Reactor integration, i.e.
[`Flux` streams](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-reactive-programming-support))
and [manual offset commits](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_example_setting_autocommitoffset_to_false_and_relying_on_manual_acking)
(i.e. `autoCommitOffset = false`).

We are trying to write an integration test with [Embedded Kafka from spring-kafka-test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#testing)
that's supposed to assert this all works, by manually reading the consumer group offset, using the [admin client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/test/rule/KafkaEmbedded.html#doWithAdmin-java.util.function.Consumer-),
before and after the test sends a message to our topic.

Tests fail intermittently. Using [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) we are now waiting up to 10 seconds to poll the offset,
and this seems to get around most of our issues, as the offset will change after around 7 seconds - but that's unsatisfactory for testing.

Is there a way to make sure Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder will write the offset change immediately once we manually acknowledge message receipt by calling `Acknowledgement.acknowledge()`?

Put differently: how can we verify `acknowledge` was called in our tests without having to wait?

We use Kotlin, Mockito and [Mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin) and thus cannot use PowerMockito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `Consumer` is not thread safe. The commits have to be done on the container thread. If the consumer is sitting in `poll()` when you ack, you have to wait for up to `pollTimeout` before the offset will be committed.

The default `pollTimeout` is 5 seconds.

You can add a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` `@Bean` to modify the `ContainerProperties`.

Comment: I just made [an improvement in this area](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/1150).

Comment: Thanks, it works. For anyone landing on this page, we used `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` for `<T>`, so the `@Bean` is a `ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>>` (Kotlin: `<*, *>`) for us. And the changes @gary-russell made to wake up the consumer sooner when in `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` mode were apparently cherry-picked for the `2.2.x` branch of `spring-kafka`.